# unable to locate the block chain file read in go-ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I have downloaded the go-ethereum code and analyzing it. It is working properly but I am not able to locate the file read and write for the block.

I have seen the eth.getBalance() function code but I could not find the file read option anywhere. It is going through the trie and get the data.

How the blocks are read by the programs?

Answer (score 2):

It's not just one flat file. It's a database, [LevelDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB) to be precise.

You can examine the chaindata folder (usually $HOME/.ethereum/chaindata on Linux) to see the files involved, but chances are you won't be able to use them directly.

If you really need the blockchain as a single file, you can use `geth export`. However, it's just creating a file for that purpose--internally, it is not using a single file at all.

Comment: yes I have noticed that it is ldb file, which is local database. I would like to find out where this database in read in file

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/ethdb) is the part of go-ethereum's source in question.